# Get result of 2 queries with 1 query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 following queries in the same table `transactions`.

`transactions` table has following 2 columns which is relevant here, `registrationId`,`total` and `totalPaid`.

To get all the paid transactions I run following query

```
Select SUM(transactions.totalPaid) as netPaid from transactions where deleted is null group by registrationId
```

To get all the unpaid transactions I run the following query

```
Select SUM(transactions.total - transactions.totalPaid) as unPaid from transactions where ((totalPaid < total) OR (total < 0)) and deleted is null group by registrationId
```

How can I combine the query and get both result in one go?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` statement to the the `unPaid` column.

```
Select sum(transactions.totalPaid) as netPaid
    , sum(case when (totalPaid < total) OR (total < 0) then transactions.total - transactions.totalPaid else 0 end) as unPaid
from transactions 
where deleted is null 
group by registrationId
```

Comment: @Metal duh.So simple.I use case on many of my queries still did not came to my mind. Thank you